# Create an new column in data frame : index in group (not unique between groups)

Tags: r, grouping, data.table

I have a data frame with two columns: the first column contains the group to which each individual belongs, and the second the individual's ID. See below:

```
df <- data.frame( group=c('G1','G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2','G2'), 
      indiv=c('indiv1','indiv1','indiv2','indiv2','indiv3',
              'indiv3','indiv4','indiv4'))

   group   indiv
1     G1  indiv1
2     G1  indiv1
3     G1  indiv2
4     G1  indiv2
5     G2  indiv3
6     G2  indiv3
7     G2  indiv4
8     G2  indiv4
```

I would like to create a new column in my data frame (retaining the long format) with the index of each individual in the group, that is:

```
   group   indiv  Ineed
1     G1  indiv1      1
2     G1  indiv1      1
3     G1  indiv2      2
4     G1  indiv2      2
5     G2  indiv3      1
6     G2  indiv3      1
7     G2  indiv4      2
8     G2  indiv4      2
```

I have tried with the data.table .N or .GRP methods, without success (nice work on data.table by the way!).

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the new `rleid` function here (from the development version v >= 1.9.5)

```
setDT(df)[, Ineed := rleid(indiv), group][]
#    group  indiv Ineed
# 1:    G1 indiv1     1
# 2:    G1 indiv1     1
# 3:    G1 indiv2     2
# 4:    G1 indiv2     2
# 5:    G2 indiv3     1
# 6:    G2 indiv3     1
# 7:    G2 indiv4     2
# 8:    G2 indiv4     2
```

Or you could convert to factors (in order to create unique groups) and then convert them back to numeric (if you using the CRAN stable version v <= 1.9.4)

```
setDT(df)[, Ineed := as.numeric(factor(indiv)), group][]
#    group  indiv Ineed
# 1:    G1 indiv1     1
# 2:    G1 indiv1     1
# 3:    G1 indiv2     2
# 4:    G1 indiv2     2
# 5:    G2 indiv3     1
# 6:    G2 indiv3     1
# 7:    G2 indiv4     2
# 8:    G2 indiv4     2
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Nice options.  I forgot about the `as.numeric(factor` approach.  Didn't know about the `rleid`

Comment: @akrun `rleid` is one of 5 new functions added by Arun just a week ago.

Answer (score 4):

In `1.9.5` (current development version), the function `frank` (and `frankv`) are exported. With that, you can do:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, col := frank(indiv, ties.method="dense"), by=group]
df
#    group  indiv col
# 1:    G1 indiv1   1
# 2:    G1 indiv1   1
# 3:    G1 indiv2   2
# 4:    G1 indiv2   2
# 5:    G2 indiv3   1
# 6:    G2 indiv3   1
# 7:    G2 indiv4   2
# 8:    G2 indiv4   2
```

You can install it by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `base R`

```
df$Ineed <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(indiv), group, 
                  FUN=function(x) cumsum(!duplicated(x))))
df
#  group  indiv Ineed
#1    G1 indiv1     1
#2    G1 indiv1     1
#3    G1 indiv2     2
#4    G1 indiv2     2
#5    G2 indiv3     1
#6    G2 indiv3     1
#7    G2 indiv4     2
#8    G2 indiv4     2
```

The data.table version would be

```
setDT(df)[, Ineed := cumsum(!duplicated(indiv)), group][]
```